# How to check whether goal has been triggered in mongoDB collection

Tags: fxm, goals

I've setup FXM between main site and subdomain sitecore sites hosted on it's own instance. And setup the personalized banner on main site based on goal triggered on fxm sub-domain site. The rule I used is xx goal triggered on current visit.

The goal needs to be triggered from FXM site on button click. My network tab shows successful 204 status code.

However, the banner doesn't get personalized on main site when I visit the main site on same browser.

I need to troubleshoot whether goal has been triggered by querying mongoDB but am not able to make decision on which collection and query to use.

Any suggestion would be good.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to validate if the page event was saved, you can run a MongoDB query against `Interactions` collection:

```
db.Interactions.find({"$and": [
    {"Pages":{"$elemMatch":
        {"PageEvents": {"$elemMatch":
            {"Name": "Your Goal Name"}}}}},
    {"SiteName": "fxm"}]
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Robo 3T](https://robomongo.org/) tool.

Next example shows how to find ***goal by name*** in ***Interactions*** collection.

```
db.getCollection('Interactions').find({Pages : {$elemMatch: {PageEvents:{$elemMatch:{Name:'FXMDemoGoal'}}}}})
```